# Как сделать таблицу умнож по 5 столбиков вверху, и 4 внизу?

Tags: c#, консоль

Пока что смог реализовать только в 1 столбик , не приходит в голову как сделать столбики(как в школьной тетради)
Пытался через if, через setcursorposition, видимо что не так делаю либо не там пишу, не в том цикле эти условия. Можно 2 варианта решения через if и через set cursor, благодарю

```
static void tabl()
{
    //  Console.WriteLine();
    for(int a = 1;a <= 9;a++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        for(int b = 1;b <= 9;b++ )  
        {                   
            Console.Write($"{a} * {b} = {a * b} \n");
                            
        }           
    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи. Но лучше все таки самому пробовать, пытаться.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    {                
        for (int b = 1; b <= 9; b++)
        {
            if (a > 5) 
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition((a - 6) * 12, b+10);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition((a - 1) * 12, b);
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine($"{a} * {b} = {a * b}");                    
        }  
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 20);
}
```

или чуток хитрее. скобки расставил для наглядности

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
    {                
        for (int b = 1; b <= 9; b++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(((a % 6) - 1 + (a / 6)) * 12, b + (a / 6 ) * 10);

            Console.WriteLine($"{a} * {b} = {a * b}");                    
        }  
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 20);
}
```

Comment: @AlexF не знал, изучу, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

`SetCursorPosition` совершенно лишний. Вы всё сделали правильно, кроме "\n", который и выводит всё в один столбик. Ещё нужно добавить выравнивание  в поле фиксированной длинны `PadRight`:

```
    static void tabl() {
        for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
            for (int b = 1; b <= 9; b++ )
                Console.Write(($"{a} * {b} = {a * b}").PadRight(12));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }   
    }
```

Ещё посмотрите на такой интересный вариант:

```
    static void tabl() {
        for (int a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++ )
                Console.Write(($"{a} * {b} = {a * b}").PadRight(12));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }   
    }
```

А вот требуемый вариант 5+4:

```
    static void tabl() {
        for (int i = 1, j = 5; i <= 6; i += 5, j = 9) {
            for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
                for (int b = i; b <= j; b++ )
                    Console.Write(($"{a} * {b} = {a * b}").PadRight(12));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }   
            Console.WriteLine();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с накоплением вывода в строковый массив. В первый элемент выводятся строки для чисел с 1 по 5, во второй - с 6 по 9, в конце элементы "склеиваются" и выводятся в консоль. Единая ширина столбцов сделана через `{a * b,2}`, где `,2` - означает выравнивание по правому краю, 2 символа. Разделение вывода по элементам массива организовано через индекс `parts[b>5?1:0]`.

```
static void tabl()
{   
    string[] parts = {"",""};
    for(int a = 0;a++<9;)
    {
        for(int b = 0;b++<9;)
        {                   
            parts[b>5?1:0]+=$"{b} * {a} = {a * b,2}\t";
        }
        parts[0]+="\n";
        parts[1]+="\n";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(parts[0]+'\n'+parts[1]);
}
```

```
1 * 1 =  1  2 * 1 =  2  3 * 1 =  3  4 * 1 =  4  5 * 1 =  5  
1 * 2 =  2  2 * 2 =  4  3 * 2 =  6  4 * 2 =  8  5 * 2 = 10  
1 * 3 =  3  2 * 3 =  6  3 * 3 =  9  4 * 3 = 12  5 * 3 = 15  
1 * 4 =  4  2 * 4 =  8  3 * 4 = 12  4 * 4 = 16  5 * 4 = 20  
1 * 5 =  5  2 * 5 = 10  3 * 5 = 15  4 * 5 = 20  5 * 5 = 25  
1 * 6 =  6  2 * 6 = 12  3 * 6 = 18  4 * 6 = 24  5 * 6 = 30  
1 * 7 =  7  2 * 7 = 14  3 * 7 = 21  4 * 7 = 28  5 * 7 = 35  
1 * 8 =  8  2 * 8 = 16  3 * 8 = 24  4 * 8 = 32  5 * 8 = 40  
1 * 9 =  9  2 * 9 = 18  3 * 9 = 27  4 * 9 = 36  5 * 9 = 45  

6 * 1 =  6  7 * 1 =  7  8 * 1 =  8  9 * 1 =  9  
6 * 2 = 12  7 * 2 = 14  8 * 2 = 16  9 * 2 = 18  
6 * 3 = 18  7 * 3 = 21  8 * 3 = 24  9 * 3 = 27  
6 * 4 = 24  7 * 4 = 28  8 * 4 = 32  9 * 4 = 36  
6 * 5 = 30  7 * 5 = 35  8 * 5 = 40  9 * 5 = 45  
6 * 6 = 36  7 * 6 = 42  8 * 6 = 48  9 * 6 = 54  
6 * 7 = 42  7 * 7 = 49  8 * 7 = 56  9 * 7 = 63  
6 * 8 = 48  7 * 8 = 56  8 * 8 = 64  9 * 8 = 72  
6 * 9 = 54  7 * 9 = 63  8 * 9 = 72  9 * 9 = 81
```

Comment: _____Зачёт_____